# Error when add ZXing Library in app for QR Code Reader in android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

Hi i am developing android application which read the QR Code. Now for that i have used ZXing library. Now when i add this library in my app it shows Error (See Image Below). I don't know y this happen plz give me proper guidence regarding it. Thanx in advance.I have refer this link [This](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/) .[image: Problem Image is here]

Comment: If you integrate to the BarcodeScanner via intent you don't have to worry about adding it as a Library to your project. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Found the problem. The Problem was the library that i have added was in the different work space. The library should be in the same workspace.